# Help with Proof in Cohn's Measure Theory: Approximation Using Regularity of Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Below is a (screenshot of a) proposition (and part of its proof) from Cohn's *Measure Theory*.

[image]

I am having trouble seeing how "relation (3) follows" from the argument given.

When trying to prove this myself, I (unsuccessfully) approached it as follows.

To show that $\mu(A)$ is the supremum in relation (3), we need to show that

(i) $\mu(K) \le \mu(A)$, for every compact subset $K$ of $A$ (which is obvious, since $\mu$ is a measure); and

(ii) If $a$ is a real number such that $\mu(K) \le a$ for every compact subset $K$ of $A$, then $\mu(A) \le a$.

I was unable to prove (ii); and so I looked at the proof which should, in theory, be a proof of (i) and (ii) above. However, I am failing to see this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHS of (3) is $\geq \mu (L-W)>\mu (A) -\epsilon$ since $K=L-H$ is a compact subset of $A$. [ Here we used the fact that supremum of  a set of real numbers is greater than or equal to any member of that set]. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary it follows that RHS $\geq \mu(A)$. The reverse inequality follows from the fact that $\mu(K) \leq \mu(A)$ for every compact set $K$ contained in $A$